# K&R Exercise 1.9 - program in infinite loop

Tags: c

I am trying to complete exercise 1-9 in K&R and I came up with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* this program will trim each group of spaces down to a single space */
int main()
{
    int c, lastCharblank;
    lastCharblank = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != ' ' || !lastCharblank)
            putchar(c);

        lastCharblank = (c == ' ');
    }

    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

While running the program through the bash command line I am able to enter text("fix     these    spaces") and then I enter cntl-d to signal an EOF. The program returns the line with all the spaces corrected, but it does not exit. It seems to be in an infinite loop. Why doesn't it exit?

Comment: It will not do like that. It will perform correctly. Which platform you are using.

Comment: You have to enter the Ctrl-D at the beginning of a line for it to register as an EOF. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19097/7084

Comment: I'm running the program from the bash command line on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way read system call is specified in POSIX standard.
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

> When EOF is received, all the bytes waiting to be read are immediately
>   passed to the process without waiting for a newline, and the EOF is
>   discarded.  Thus, if there are no bytes waiting (that is, the EOF
>   occurred at the beginning of a line), a byte count of zero shall be
>   returned from the read(), representing an end-of-file indication

`getchar` in the I/O library is implemented using read system call which is line oriented. That means `read()` delivers one line at a time to the caller. The I/O library stores the bytes returned by read() in a buffer and in case of `getchar`, delivers one byte at a time to the process.

The fact that `read()` is line oriented leads to different behavior of Cntl-D depending upon whether the input is at the beginning of a line or not. According to spec, Cntl-D at the beginning of a line signals EOF immediately.

However,  Cntl-D in the middle of a line acts differently. It sends the remaining bytes to the process and EOF is discarded. That is why another Cntl-D is required to signal EOF to the process.

Comment: That's what I was doing wrong. I was hitting cntl-d immediately after entering the text so the program was discarding the EOF. That's a big help. Thanks ThomasG!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I seems you are using a platform on which CTRL-D is not the right key binding for sending an EOF. E.g. on Windows, it's usually CTRL-Z.

**EDIT:** And yes, as others have already stated, the EOF needs to be at the beginning of a line, so you need to send a newline first.

Comment: I am on running the program from bash on Linux Mint so it is ctrl-d, I was just entering it immediately after the text without entering a newline first. Thanks!!!